# How do I make to separate parameters to print not be space separated

Tags: python

Example:

```
Number1 = 25
Print('$', Number1)
```

The output would be:

```
$ 25
```

I’m wondering if I can make the output be

```
$25
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) like:

```
print('${}'.format(number1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sep` parameter:

```
print("$", Number1, sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the traditional way also

```
print('$'+str(Number1))
```

But don't forget to convert int to str